# Sime PHP-Script: XSS attack possible?

Tags: javascript, php, security, xss

I found following code-snippet and want to prove, that it is not secure and instead, htmlentities() should be used, instead of this own implementation.

Can someone see a attack-vector for `$input`, which contains JavaScript-Code, which is then executed in this simple code example?

```
<?php
function sanitizeJSString($strValue) {
    $strValue = str_replace("\\", "\\\\", $strValue);
    $strValue = str_replace("\"", "\\\"", $strValue);
    $strValue = str_replace("'", "\\'", $strValue);
    $strValue = str_replace("`", "\\`", $strValue);
    $strValue = str_replace("$", "\\$", $strValue);
    return $strValue;
}

$input = 'this comes from user-input';
?>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script>
        var foo = "<?php echo sanitizeJSString( $input ) ?>";
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

I understand that this is not code which you should use in production, I just try to prove to someone, that this code, which was written, is not secure and there is a possible attack vector.

Comment: why not using `htmlspecialchars()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider `$input = "\n</script><script src=https://example.com/xss.js>"`. That will result in html like below allowing for XSS attacks.

```html
 <script>
        var foo = "
</script><script src=https://example.com/xss.js>";
    </script>
```

Instead what you can do is use `json_encode`. That approach is more robust. As long as `$input` is a string, `foo` will also be a string and all special characters will be escaped for you.

```php
var foo = <?= json_encode( $input ) ?>;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, you are right, this is exactly working!